# Use of drivers into the Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a framework where I have used Webdriver instance

Comment: I would use 2 separate instances... sorta depends on your requirements, but you can run them both at the same time and compare results when done, which would make for a nice cross-platform test since they're both running in similar timeframes. Maybe someone has an elegant solution to wrap all those types to re-use code?  I think as is IOSDriver extends AppiumDriver extends WebDriver?  There's some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117578/how-to-only-have-one-driver-that-can-be-used-as-webdriver-or-appiumdriver

Comment: RemoteWebDriver driver = new Chrome/FirefoxDriver ();
RemoteWebDriver driver = new IOSDriver ();
how about using this way?

Comment: I've never used appium or iosdriver before.  You'd suggested before that wouldn't work, but you might be able to cast just for the functions specific to appium style drivers.  Case/switch based on type... those functions just wouldn't run for standard webdrivers... (Chrome/Firefox/IE/Edge drivers would be interchangeable.)